# Checking if a string is a number, then converting that number to an int?

Tags: c++

The 'program' is to take input in then spit the string back out on seperate lines and all numbers are to be multiplied by two in this case.

My issue occurs when a number is input after a white space.
Example

```
Sentence: 12 fish
```

Outputs:

```
24     
fish
```

But...

```
Sentence: there are 12
```

Outputs:

```
there
are
0
```

The program I have written:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str;
    int number = 811;
    cout << "Sentence: ";
    getline(cin,str);

    istringstream iss(str);

     while(iss)
     {
            bool ree = 0;
            string word;
            iss >> word;

            if(isdigit(word[0]))
            {
                stringstream(str) >> number;
                number = (number * 2);
                cout << number << endl;
                ree = 1;
                number = 911;
            }

           if(!ree)
           {
            cout << word << endl;
           }

           ree = 0;

      }
}
```

Hopefully it's something small I am not seeing! 
Thanks for the help in advanced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that

```
stringstream(str) >> number;
```

creates a fresh string stream from the initial sentence, then tries to extract from it into `number`. Of course that will fail (as the first word in the sentence is not a number). If you wonder why `number` was set to 0, that's because on failure, the `stringstream::operator>>` zeros the argument (since C++11).

> "*If extraction fails, zero is written to value and failbit is set.*" ...

Before C++11, it left the argument unchanged. See the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) for more details.

The correct way is to use a conversion from string to `int` (or `long`), namely [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), and replace that line by

```
try{
    number = std::stoi(word); 
}
catch(std::exception& e){
    std::cout << "error converting" << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `stoi` to parse the input like this:

```
int num = std::stoi(input);
```

Answer (score -1):

using `stoi` is easy, and you can lazily catch the exception by the following:

```
if(!stoi(string)){
    std::cout << "caught a non integer string" << endl;
}
```

Comment: No, you need to `catch` the exception that's thrown by `std::stoi`. Otherwise what happens with `std::stoi("0")`?

Comment: I suppose I had not considered that, is there some case where this would also fail when used to catch file IO exceptions?

Comment: The problem I see is that your test will never catch the error, as `stoi(string)` will just throw an exception so the inside of the `if` won't be executed. Not sure what you mean by file IO exceptions? `stoi` will just throw if it cannot convert.

Comment: Well what I mean by IO is that I often use this convention to check for a file in a directory. Like this `if(!ifstream('file')){no file}`. I have also done this with `stod()`.